Action of an "automorphism" of L-schemes
I'm studying something related about schemes over a field and I would like to help me to understand "intuitively" what´s going on:
Let $L$ be a field and $\sigma: L \longrightarrow L$ an automorphism. Let $A$ be a $L$-algebra, A commutative with 1. We can take the fiber product as $L$-schemes $L \otimes_L A$. Intuitively (I think so) a point $x \in Spec(L\otimes A)$ corresponds to a prime ideal $L \otimes \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$. Then, simplifying the idea I can think $x$ as a formal sum $\Sigma l \otimes a$, where $l \in L$ and $a \in \mathfrak{p}$.
Now, let´s consider the homomorphism of schemes
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\sigma}=Spec(\sigma)\times Id_{Spec(A)}: L \otimes A \longrightarrow L \otimes A,
\end{equation*}
where $Spec(\sigma):SpecL \longleftarrow SpecL$ is the induced by the automorphism $\sigma$. How $\tilde{\sigma}(x)$ looks like in terms of tensors?
I think that $\tilde{\sigma}(x)$ is the ideal correspond to the ideal whose terms are of the type $\Sigma \sigma(l) \otimes a$, I mean, is "the same ideal" but with the coefficients of $L$ "moved" by the automorphism. Am I wrong? Is there an example where I can see this phenomenon?
Every single help will be very appreciated!

Be careful, you are using a tensor product over $L$ but your automorphism does not have the same action on $L$ on both sides of the tensor product, so it's not well-defined.

@CaptainLama what if A be a $L_0$-algebra, $\sigma \in Aut(L/L_0)$ and take the tensor product over $L_0$ with the inclusion $L_0 \subset L$?

Yes that would be fine.
